# Show $ \sum_{n=1}^\infty { {\left(-1\right)^{n+1}} \over \Gamma(n+1)} = 1 - \frac1e $

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Show

> $$
> \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}{\left(-1\right)^{n+1} \over \Gamma\left(n + 1\right)}
> =1 - {1 \over {\rm e}}
> $$

This may be related to $$e=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac1{n!}$$  I am having trouble making the connection, though.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Recall [Maclaurin series for exponential function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series#List_of_Maclaurin_series_of_some_common_functions)
$$
e^x=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{x^n}{n!}=1+x+\frac{x^2}{2!}+\frac{x^3}{3!}+\cdots\qquad;\qquad\text{for all $x$},\tag1
$$
and property of [gamma function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function)
$$
\Gamma(n+1)=n!\qquad;\qquad\text{for $n$ is a positive integer}.\tag2
$$
Putting $x=-1$ to $(1)$ and using $(2)$ yield
$$
\frac1e=1+\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{n}}{\Gamma(n+1)}\qquad\iff\qquad\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{\Gamma(n+1)}=1-\frac1e.
$$

Answer (score 2):

$$\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}\lbrace[ \frac{x^i}{i!} \rbrace] = e^x$$

Recall:
$$\Gamma(x+1) = x!$$

Substitute $x = -1$ into the first line formula, then subtract 1 (to shift the bounds to start from $i=0$) and then negate the whole thing (so the minus signs line up correctly) to find the result you are looking for